# Regarding private/permissioned blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, permissioned-chain

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with my concerns: Let's say we are a bank consortium and we own a permissioned/private blockchain. Is this possible for us to open our blockchain through API or SDK so that external innovators can develop applications on top of our blockchain without harming the privacy of the data stored on our blockchain?

I am not a technical guy but interested in innovation topic. If possible, please answer in layman's terms.

Comment: you say without harming the privacy of the data...but how is data kept private from the other banks in the blockchain consortium ? Banks cannot share between them their clients private data right?

Comment: The private blockchain that I mean here should only be used for only B2B industrial use cases, not B2C use cases. Of course there would be privacy concerns between members in the consortium, but it is not in the scope of my question.

Comment: my point was that if there is no privacy to begin with then nothing can be harmed...it was in the scope of your question since it was mentioend as a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could make a public testnet. Which has the same functionality as your priv net but has dummy data. People could develop and test here. Before presumably selling it to someone who has access to the priv chain.